# exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' while uploading file to server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Iam new in asp.net, ajax and c#. Iám trying to save image on server by the following example:

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="file" name="postedFile" />
        <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" />
        <progress id="fileProgress" style="display: none"></progress>
        <hr />
        <span id="lblMessage" style="color: Green"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").on("click", "#btnUpload", function () {   
$.ajax({
                url: 'Handler.ashx',
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (file) {
                    $("#fileProgress").hide();
                    $("#lblMessage").html("<b>" + file.name + "</b> has been uploaded.");
                },
                xhr: function () {
                    var fileXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (fileXhr.upload) {
                        $("progress").show();
                        fileXhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                $("#fileProgress").attr({
                                    value: e.loaded,
                                    max: e.total
                                });
                            }
                        }, false);
                    }
                    return fileXhr;
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Added Generic Handler:

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace RateEatPresentation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Handler
    /// </summary>
    public class Handler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //Check if Request is to Upload the File.
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                //Fetch the Uploaded File.
                HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];

                //Set the Folder Path.
                string folderPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/UsersUploadedImages/");

                //Set the File Name.
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

                //Save the File in Folder.
                postedFile.SaveAs(folderPath + fileName);

                //Send File details in a JSON Response.
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                    new
                    {
                        name = fileName
                    });
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                context.Response.Write(json);
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But Iam getting exceprion "An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code". I tried to find something similar but unfortunately didn't succeeded:
[image]

Comment: ... `additional information: Maximum request length exceeded` - looks like you already have the info you need

Comment: 1 try with a small file (text file with 1 character) 2 if that works search SO for how to increase maximum request length on ASP.Net requests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum request length exceeded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the image may be too big size, you need ajust the web.config to sopport them.
By default IIS supports 4MB you can change that in Web.config

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

And

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

You must change the maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength